Why Rich-Text Image URL not getting updated in record?
Why before Insert or Update doesn't update the RichText Image URL?
To Replicate
New Field:
Created a new RichText field in case object 'Comments__c'
Take a screenshot and paste the image field.
Trigger
try to replace your org instance image URL to 'org--preprod.sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com' in trigger.
trigger Case_Before_insert on Case (before insert,before update) {
    for(Case cse : trigger.New) {
        cse.Comments__c = cse.Comments__c.replace('drive-java-9355-dev-ed.scratch.file.force.com','org--preprod.sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com');
        cse.Comments__c = cse.Comments__c.replace('Test','Test2');
        system.debug(cse.Comments__c);
    }
}

My Debug Output:
<p>Test2</p><p><br></p><p><img src="https://org--preprod.sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=500F300000CX4Ci&amp;feoid=00NF300000Gn5Pl&amp;refid=0EMF30000007N5g" alt="image.png"></img></p>


Query:

Please see the inspect image URL is not changing.
Even debugging is working as expected also 'Test' keyword is updated as 'Test2' but why is the URL not updating in RichText ?

have you checked the value in the database?

added query screenshot, still not updated

Got following update from salesforce support,
Hope it will be helpful.
Hi Ragul,
I am XXXX from Salesforce Development Support Team. I have taken ownership of your case and I will be your point of contact for the next steps.
I understand your concern as outlined in the case description, and I have reviewed the code you shared. I would like to inform you that the issue is not with your code; the trigger appears to be correctly implemented.
However, the challenge arises from your attempt to replace the domain of the image source from file.force.com to salesforce-sites.com. This replacement is not feasible due to security reasons. Changing the domain from an internal user domain (file.force.com) to an external community domain (salesforce-sites.com) is not valid and is expected behavior as part of Salesforce's security protocols.
Additionally, I attempted to update the alt attribute of the  tag, which was reflected in the inspect window. This confirms that domain changes are not permitted and should not be done as per Salesforce's security policies.
Please let me know if you have any further questions or need additional assistance and I will get back to you on priority.
